# Excel Time addition

Tags: excel

First time poster and new joiner.

So I’m having a little difficulty is attempting to take a “lapsed time” with a format of 0:00:00 from a stated time (in this case I’m using a time stamp)

What I would like to achieve is the following.

Let’s say I attain some data from an external source that shows me the lapsed time someone hasn’t been logged In from their expected time. Now unfortunately the time due isn’t readily available so I want to put in A1 (CTRL + shift and ; for my time stamp) and then in B1 I want to minus the lapsed time.  And in C1 a subtraction formula that will give me (there or about a the time that should be due to log in)

The issue I’m facing is this, I’ve tried a simple minus, a TIME function and both give a value error

I’m unsure whether firstly the fact that my time stamp being only hours and minutes is an issue but also when I attempt to remove the seconds from the lapsed time it won’t easily format out without manual input from me.

I feel like I’m being stupid here but cannot seem to get say;

14:55 to minus 0:25:00 to give me 14:00 !!

For clarity I have tried to format the time to include seconds but still not use...

Is there an easy way to conver the lapsed time to minutes for easier use of TIME ?

Answer (score 0):

> 14:55 to minus 0:25:00 to give me 14:00

I think you wanted to say "... to give me 14:30".

Well, you can do subtraction of time values:
[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understood, do you want a negative value in `B1`?

Comment: I did thank you. This on the face of it would be fine but the problem is, the numbers I’m pulling are formatted as 0:00:00 and I don’t seem to be able to change them easily with formatting?? 

I’ll get on the computer to try and show you what I mean shortly and hopefully that will give more clarity. As I assume in the above you’re just using =time to subtract ?

Comment: format can be 0:00:00, but it does not tell the data type. Is it text? I am simply using `-` as can be seen. I have not used `=time`